# How to get image to appear for Linkedin social share

Tags: social-sharing-buttons, linkedin

I've got a blog with social sharing activated.  I've been able to get images to appear properly when someone shares a post for Facebook, Google+ and Twitter.

However, when I click to share through LinkedIn the image isn't being pulled up.  It just shows a blank space where the image should show.  When I look at the source code for where the image should show, it shows that the correct image is set, but the one saved on Linkedin's servers is 1x1 pixel.

Any ideas, I've tried to fix this for a few days.

Comment: Maybe this post on StackOverflow would help: [How to successfully implement og:image for the LinkedIn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042786/how-to-successfully-implement-ogimage-for-the-linkedin)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been sufficiently addressed at Stack Overflow

Comment: LinkedIn uses OpenGraph tags, like Facebook, so it gets the image from `<og:image>` tags in the header. Also like Facebook, it will cache the image. For LinkedIn, that can be up to 7 days. So if someone else shared or you tested without an image, it won't appear because the cache. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin